# Ruby: Get the value if end_with? is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looking for a clean way to return the characters of a string if `end_with?` evaluates to true.
i.e.

```
s = "my_name"
name = s.end_with?("name")

puts name
>> "name"
```

My use case would look somewhat like this:

```
file_name = "some_pdf"

permitted_file_types = %w(image pdf)

file_type = file_name.end_with?(*permitted_file_types)

puts file_type
>> "pdf"
```

Comment: To my knowledge "image" is not generally an extension. You can get the extension from a file by using `File.extname(file_name)` however if you are looking to check MIME types this is not the best way to go about this (there are libraries for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
"my_name".scan(/name\z/)[0]
#=> "name"

"something".scan(/name\z/)[0]
#=> nil
```

Comment: even simpler: `"my_name"[/name\z/]`

Comment: If we are using a regex literal then we can take advantage of `Regexp#=~` and named capture groups e.g. `/(?<my_var>name)\z/ =~ "my_name"; my_var #=> "name"`

Answer (score 0):

May be using `match` and `\z` (end of string)?

```
string = "my_name"

suffix1 = "name"
suffix2 = "name2"
```

In Ruby >= 3.1

```
result1 = %r{#{suffix1}\z}.match(string)&.match(0)
# => "name"

result2 = %r{#{suffix2}\z}.match(string)&.match(0)
# => nil
```

In Ruby < 3.1

```
result1 = %r{#{suffix1}\z}.match(string)&.[](0)
# => "name"

result2 = %r{#{suffix2}\z}.match(string)&.[](0)
# => nil
```

Just for fun trick with `tap`:

```
string.tap { |s| break s.end_with?(suffix1) ? suffix1 : nil }
# => "name"

string.tap { |s| break s.end_with?(suffix2) ? suffix2 : nil }
# => nil
```

Comment: `string.tap { |s| break s.end_with?(suffix1) ? suffix1 : nil }` is better written as `string.yield_self { |s| suffix1 if s.end_with?(suffix1)}` or `yield_self`'s alias `then` e.g. `string.then { |s| suffix1 if s.end_with?(suffix1)}`

Answer (score 0):

ruby already has a `String#end_with?` method, going back to at least version 2.7.1, maybe earlier. But it returns a boolean and you want the matched string to be returned. You're calling a method on an instance of `String`, so you're apparently wanting to add a method to the `String` class.

```rb
class String #yeah we're monkey patching!
  def ends_with?(str) #don't use end_with.. it's already defined
    return str if self.end_with?(str)
  end
end

#now 
s="my_name"
s.ends_with?("name") #=> "name"
```

But I really wouldn't bother with all that... I'd just work with what Ruby provides:

```rb
s = "my_name"
str = "name"
result = str if s.end_with?(str)
```